# How to get a Hardcopy of a dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe and I want to print it using a printer or get a hard copy of a dataframe. I have almost 30 columns and 100s of rows in that dataframe. I just want to get a hard copy of it in any format. I tried making a PDF of it and then press Ctrl+P but the dataframe values were not readable. Same with HTML too. I just want the data to be readable. How can I do so? i am creating an applications for those people who are not really familiar using computers so can the answer be more simple i got it that i can use to_excel and to_csv also but then the user has to go to excel file and click on print.i want it that it can be more simple and easy for the user.

Comment: could you please provide us with some data? and show us about unreadable characters.

Comment: the data is readable but there are so many rows and columns it overlaps the data which make it unreadabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing out a large dataframe will always result in being limited to the paper size you have available.  A4/letter is, I guess, normal - unless you have a CAD plotter doing A0 :o).  Large tables will have to span pages across and down and it gets confusing to read - the job is to understand the data in the table not deal with how the table is presented, right?

This may not help, but you could try [dataframe-image](https://pypi.org/project/dataframe-image/) as an additional potential output method (at least the image created isn't an ugly unstyled HTML table).

Be warned if the frame is large it can take over 30 seconds to create the image and the `.png` file output can be ~3MB in size.

**Whole image:**

[image]

**Viewing at 100%:**

You can of course zoom in etc. and see the data.

[image]

**Example code:**

```
# https://pypi.org/project/dataframe-image/
import dataframe_image as dfi
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #just for the creation of a dummy frame

data = {'Col1' : np.random.choice(10, 100)} 
data.update({'Val{}'.format(i) : np.random.randn(100) for i in range(28)})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.shape)
# (100, 29) - 100 rows by "almost 30 columns" ;o)

dfi.export(df, 'dataframe.png', max_cols=-1)
```

Do note the slow running and consider if it will hang your computer.

```
%timeit dfi.export(df, 'dataframe.png', max_cols=-1)
35.1 s ± 2.16 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

To limit the columns included use the `max_cols=` parameter.  Setting to `max_cols=-1` gets all columns and will be the slowest.

Comment: dfi.export(df, 'dataframe.png', max_cols=-1) 
plz explain this line

Comment: There isn't all that much to it.  For more information see https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image

Comment: Scroll down the page to As a Python Library and see the options `>>> dfi.convert('path/to/your_notebook.ipynb', to='pdf', use='latex', center_df=True, max_rows=30, max_cols=10, execute=False, save_notebook=False, limit=None, document_name=None, table_conversion='chrome' chrome_path=None, latex_command=None, output_dir=None, )`

Comment: Thanks sir for ur help:)